# How to remove "<span class="caret"></span>" if does not added sub category under parent category

Tags: codeigniter, dropdown, caret

I have to hide dropdown "caret". If does not added Sub categories in codeigniter.

Here is my code : 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <?php
 $this->load->module('store_categories');
 foreach ($parent_categories as $key => $value) {
    $parent_cat_id = $key;
    $parent_cat_title = $value;
 ?>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><?= $parent_cat_title ?>
      <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <?php
          $query = $this->store_categories->get_where_custom('parent_cat_id', $parent_cat_id);
          foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row->cat_title.'</a></li>';
          }
          ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: use javascript.to hide caret.

Comment: I am new try to something learn, can you help me how to do this?

Comment: Do not hide it with Javascript, if Javascript is switched off in the browser, then it will not hide the caret. Hide it from server-side, see my answer about how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to generate the query content, then check and use its value.

```
<?php
    function getQueryContent($parent_cat_id, $that) {
        $queryContent = "";
        $query = $that->store_categories->get_where_custom('parent_cat_id', $parent_cat_id);
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $queryContent .= '<li><a href="#">'.$row->cat_title.'</a></li>';
        }
        return $queryContent;
    }
?>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <?php
 $this->load->module('store_categories');
 foreach ($parent_categories as $key => $value) {
    $parent_cat_id = $key;
    $parent_cat_title = $value;
    $queryContent = getQueryContent($parent_cat_id, $this);
 ?>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><?= $parent_cat_title ?>
      <?php
      if ($queryContent) {
      ?>
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <?php
          echo $queryContent;
          ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but see following error : Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'

Filename: views/top_nav.php

Line Number: 19

Comment: @ShameemMridha, the error did not appear in your comment, but I think the problem was that I was using $this inside the function. To remedy that problem, I have changed it to $that, which is a parameter and I pass $this to it.

Comment: @ShameemMridha with the current version of the answer do you still get an error?

Comment: Thanks again, yes 'caret' are hide but now sub category are not showing.

Comment: @ShameemMridha you are right, please test again with the code in the edited answer.

Comment: Yes brother! Excellent problem are solved. But I have another problem when click root category and drop down category open it is fantastic, but problem is which root category has no sub sub category it showing a blank drop down div.

Comment: @ShameemMridha do you want to hide the dropdown as well in that case, or do you need content there?

Comment: @ShameemMridha you are welcome. If the answer solved the problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer to let others having similar problems know what the solution was.